# c# control value problem at form load

Tags: c#, events, forms, combobox, custom-attribute

like coffee for an insomniac, i have another question to post.

in a form's load event, i create and initialize controls based on attributes of a class passed as an argument into the form's constructor. the comboboxes and checkboxes fail early (method "initializeControls()") into the form creation but not later (method "resetData()"). i fail to understand as both are called during event "SomeForm_Load(sender, e)". did i do something as basic as use the wrong event? as stated in my earlier question posts, i'm new to c#. any guidance appreciated. feel free to tell me if i use far too much reflection, too, :D.

the pseudo code, for the gist of my problem:

```
public class SomeForm : Form
{
  #region fields
  private int _id { get; set; }
  private int _id2 { get; set; }
  #endregion fields
  ...
  public SomeForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
  public SomeForm(int id, int id2) : this()
  {
    _id = id;
    _id2 = id2;
  }

  #region init
  private void SomeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    method1(); // fails
    method2(); // works
  }
  private void method1()
  {
    var ds = new []{1,2};
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.DataSource = ds;
    cb.SelectedValue = _id; // <== this is the problem. these two
    this.Controls.Add(cb);  // <== steps should be switched.
  }
  private void method2()
  {
    cb.SelectedValue = _id2;
  }
  ...
}
```

the real code:

```
public class SomeForm : Form
{
  ...
  #region fields
  ...
  private MultiState.Update _child { get; set; }
  protected object data { get; set; }
  private Type _masterType { get; set; }
  private List<PropertyInfo> _mpks = new List<PropertyInfo>();
  private User _user { get; set; }
  #endregion fields
  ...
  public SomeForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
  public SomeForm(User user, Type amaster, object aobject, Dictionary<string, object> astate) : this()
  {
    data = aobject;
    _masterType = amaster;
    dataState = astate;
    _user = user;
  }

  #region init
  private void SomeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    initialize();
  }
  private void initialize()
  {
    tsData.Visible = false;
    if (data != null)
    {
      initializeControls(); // FAILS!! without exception
      dataId = DataService.GetPrimaryKeyValue(data);
      resetData(); // SUCCEEDS
    }
  }
  private void initializeControls()
  {
    ...
    ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
    cb.Enabled = fdEnabled; // correctly read from linq datacontext custom attribute
    cb.FormattingEnabled = true;
    cb.Location = new Point(x, y);
    cb.Name = _CP_COMBOBOX + pi.Name;
    cb.Size = new Size(_WIDTH_CODE, _HEIGHT_SINGLE);
    cb.TabIndex = i;
    cb.TabStop = true;
    cb.Leave += new EventHandler(this.ctlEdit_Leave);

    // set drop-down
    cb.DataSource = domain; // correctly populated from service class
    cb.ValueMember = "Id";
    cb.DisplayMember = "Label";

    // set default
    if (fdDefault != null)
    {
```

THE ASSIGNMENT BELOW FAILS!! the desired value calculates correctly (wth, when uncommented), but it is simply ignored without any exception.

```
      //object wth = GetDomainKeyAsIdentifierSafe(domain, fdDefault, _user); // correctly parsed
      cb.SelectedValue = GetDomainKeyAsIdentifierSafe(domain, fdDefault, _user); // HUGE FAIL!!
    }
    ...
  }
  #endregion init
  ...
  #region persistence
  ...
  protected string resetData()
  {
    string rc = "";
    if (!isDataNew()) // this form only modal
    {
      //resetDataState();
      #region bind-object-vs-set
      foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
      {
        try
        {
          if (control.Name.StartsWith(_CP_TEXTBOX))
          {
            MethodInfo mi = data.GetType().GetMethod(DataService.LINQ_GET + control.Name.Substring(_CP_TEXTBOX.Length));
            object value = mi.Invoke(data, null);
            control.Text = value == null ? "" : value.ToString();
          }
          else if (control.Name.StartsWith(_CP_CHECKBOX))
          {
            #region bind-object-vs-set-cbx
            bool ck = false;
            string scontrol = control.Name.Substring(_CP_CHECKBOX.Length);
            MethodInfo mi = data.GetType().GetMethod(DataService.LINQ_GET + scontrol);
            object value = mi.Invoke(data, null);
            if (value != null)
            {
              if (value.GetType() == typeof(bool))
              {
                ck = (bool)value;
              }
              else if (value.GetType() == typeof(Nullable<bool>))
              {
                Nullable<bool> nvalue = (Nullable<bool>)value;
                if (nvalue.HasValue)
                  ck = nvalue.Value;
                else
                  ck = AtsService.GetDefaultBoolean(data.GetType(), scontrol);
              }
            }
            CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)control;
            cbx.Checked = ck;
            #endregion bind-object-vs-set-cbx
          }
          else if (control.Name.StartsWith(_CP_COMBOBOX))
          {
            MethodInfo mi = data.GetType().GetMethod(DataService.LINQ_GET + control.Name.Substring(_CP_COMBOBOX.Length));
            object value = mi.Invoke(data, null);
            ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)control;
```

THE ASSIGNMENT BELOW MYSTERIOUSLY WORKS!!

```
            cb.SelectedValue = value == null ? FormService.NOSELECTION_ID : value; // but this one works!!
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ...
  #endregion persistence
}
```

edit: added bigger flags at success and fail points.

Comment: _the comboboxes and checkboxes fail early._ How exactly do they fail? what exception are you getting?

Comment: could you provide the exact error, what do you mean by "fail" here??

Comment: i'm not getting any exception. when i set the value inside method "initilizeComponents()", it ignores my value (default for a new record, set at control creation) like an uppity debutant. it accepts value (from object passed into constructor) later into the _Load event with method "resetData()". that make sense? i've got comments in the code up there, but it's maybe a big chunk of code.

Answer (score 1):

Though your problem is not clear enough, but i think you are creating a local variables inside "initialzeControls()" and you are expecting them to be available at the class level somehow..

you have to create controls at the class level for that.. may be i'm wrong, because your error is not clear. you have to present your problem clearly, what you are expecting and why and what you are actually getting..

Comment: i am indeed using variables at the class level. the commented-out "wth" was only there for me to see if the value was pulling back correctly. that is, if the error was with the called function or with the calling routine. thanks for taking time to review this so early in the (nyc) morning!

Comment: you have to check that, what GetDomainKeyAsIdentifierSafe(domain, fdDefault, _user) returns is contained in the "domain" that you have assigned as the datasource of the cb in above lines..

Comment: it is when i debug, but i see what you mean. i'll test for that condition outside the debugger.

Comment: wait, i mis-read that. the value is indeed in there. i wrote my data model with good integrity. however, what i mis-read, i think that tho i set "cb.Datasource" to "domain", i don't think it's ~available~ yet. maybe c# has to think it over. i dunno.

Comment: this line of thought led to a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to follow your wall of code since you have used ambiguous names and haven't documented your code properly.

I suggest you narrow down your problem by setting breakpoints and stepping into your code: `F11`.